# Is possible that a JCombobox has 2 ItemListeners?

Tags: java, listener, jcombobox

I have 3 JComboBoxes. The first shows the school year of a kid. The second shows the class of the kid and the third shows the children of that school year and of that class. I want that when I select an option of the first JComboBox, at the second JComboBox appears one option or another (depending of the selection of the first JComboBox). The problem is that also, I want select an option in the second JComboBox and in the third appears one option or another (depending of the selection of the second JComboBox). I have tried it a lot and I don't know how to do it. I have tried actionlisteners too, but it didn't work. Please, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: From your description, why do you think you need more than one item listener per combo box? Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: Show us code for an attempt of 2 `ComboBox`es where one restricts the choices of the other. Make sure we can run it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that shows how you can populate a second combo box based on the selection in the first combo box:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JComboBox<String> mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> subComboBox;
    private Hashtable<String, String[]> subItems = new Hashtable<String, String[]>();

    public ComboBoxTwo()
    {
        String[] items = { "Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit" };
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox<String>( items );
        mainComboBox.addActionListener( this );

        //  prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
        mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
        add( mainComboBox );

        //  Create sub combo box with multiple models

        subComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
        add( subComboBox );

        String[] subItems1 = { "Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);

        String[] subItems2 = { "Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);

        String[] subItems3 = { "Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String item = (String)mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get( item );

        if (o == null)
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel() );
        }
        else
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( (String[])o ) );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ComboBoxTwo() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to explain a little my code. I receive for another class a JSon object, because the information is in a database. The other classes are ClasInf and StudentsInf. It's a JSon object so I have to get the object and then change it to a String, for put it on the jcombobox. All the JCombobox are in the same class. Please if you don't understand something tell me it. I have tried to translate the whole answer

This is my first JCombobox.

```
for(int c=0;c<arrayClassroom.size();c++){
        JsonObject clas = arrayClassroom.getJsonObject(c);
        comboBoxYear.addItem(clas.getString("name"));
    }
```

And this is the second and the third

```
ItemListener itemlistener= new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent eventCombo){
            comboBoxYear.removeAllItems();
            comboBoxYear.addItem("Class");
            clase = new ClasInf();
            String cursoPru = comboBoxYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
            arrayClas = clase.getclase(cursoPru);

            for(int c=0;c<arrayClas.size();c++){
                JsonObject curso = arrayClas.getJsonObject(c);
                comboBoxYear.addItem(curso.getString("name_class"));
            }   

            comboBoxStudents.removeAllItems();
            comboBoxStudents.addItem("Students");
            students= new StudentsInf();
            String clases = comboBoxClase.getSelectedItem().toString();
            arrayStudent = student.getStudent(clases);

            for(int j=0;j<arrayStudent.size();j++){
                JsonObject clase = arrayStudent.getJsonObject(j);
                comboBoxStudents.addItem(clase.getString("nombre"));
            }
        }
    };

    comboBoxYear.addItemListener(itemlistener);
```